# Credit attribution for prediction in recurrent neural nets

Tags: deep-learning, rnn

Consider a recurrent neural net, which has access two inputs sequences

> x1,x2,x3,x4....

and

> s1,s2,s3,s4...

It emits a predictions

> p1,p2,p3,p4....

where

```
pi = RNN(si,xi,hi)
```

where hi is the hidden state formed after looking at s,x from t=0....i-1

I am interested in understanding how much of sequence s and sequence x from t=0..i had an effect on the prediction p at t=i.

I want two scalars between [0,1] which sum to 1 to represent the effect of both the sequences. Say the scalars are 0.01 and 0.99 meaning sequence s was mostly ignored.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems you are asking about feature importance and how to aggregate those. You may want to add a bit more details about your implementation.